# Adding SSL certificates to HAProxy with certbot

Tags: web, devops, load-balancing, haproxy, high-availability

I am trying to configure my Nginx server to act as my primary load balancer. I have done the necessary package installation with certbot but the problem comes in when I try to configure my haproxy.cfg file.

All the default haproxy configuratins are left untouched , so i added these lines

```
frontend www-https-frontend
    bind *:80
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/letsencrypt/archive/www.example.tech/fullchain.pem
    http-request redirect scheme https unless { ssl_fc }
    http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Proto https

    default_backend www-backend

backend www-backend
    balance roundrobin
    server web-01 54.90.15.228:80 check
    server web-02 35.153.66.157:80 check
```

But when I run `sudo haproxy -c -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg`, I get this error:

```
[NOTICE]   (70084) : haproxy version is 2.5.14-1ppa1~focal
[NOTICE]   (70084) : path to executable is /usr/sbin/haproxy
[ALERT]    (70084) : config : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:39] : 'bind *:443' : unable to stat SSL certificate from file '/etc/letsencrypt/archive/www.codingbro.tech/fullchain.pem' : No such file or directory.
[ALERT]    (70084) : config : Error(s) found in configuration file : /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
[ALERT]    (70084) : config : Fatal errors found in configuration.
```

When the certificate was generated they provided this exact path for the fullchain `/etc/letsencrypt/archive/www.example.tech/fullchain.pem`.
Any help would be much appreciated